# Oracle working with to_date

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

```
SELECT   TO_DATE (2014 || '.09.30', 'yyyy.mm.dd')
       - TO_DATE (2104 || '.07.01', 'yyyy.mm.dd')
          AS "Wtf",
       TO_DATE (2014 || '.09.30', 'yyyy.mm.dd') AS date_to,
       TO_DATE (2104 || '.07.01', 'yyyy.mm.dd') AS date_from
  FROM DUAL
```

Returning -32781    2014/09/30/ 2104/07/01/

Why i getting -32781?
I expecting something about -90...

Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be the year is 2104 not 2014?

Comment: You have Sharp eyes :)

Comment: @user2879235 . . . This would appear to be the correct answer.  If you agree, you should accept it as correct.

Comment: oh... long work day... thx :)

Comment: I know the feeling... been there many times myself